# Time entries in calendar automatically display month/day/year

Tags: macos, calendar

When in month view, Calendar in Mavericks (os x 10.9.4) normally displays an event followed by the time. Now calendar automatically adds (after the time) month/day/year. For example, if in month view for September 16, I enter "Jury Duty 8:30 AM," into the box for September 16, Calendar automatically expands this to "July Duty 8:30 AM 9/16/14. Any way to get rid of month/day/year?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest checking your language & region settings in Mac preferences, particularly under the Advanced options to see if you have an unexpected region or calendar setting there.